# python to call sql server procedure (2.7)

Tags: python, sql-server, database, python-2.7, stored-procedures

Never use python before, here want to using procedure already written in SQL server Script, then write a python application connect to database (already connected) rather than JAVA, because this is much easier. 
Let user to give an input as the @Departments, then calculate the average of that Department's average salary. 
My sql server procedure code:

```
 CREATE PROC aaatest @ Departments varchar(40)
        AS
        BEGIN
        SELECT  AVG(P.Salary)  
        FROM Company P
        WHERE P.Department = @Departments

        END
```

please write the a python application to get the input then pass to the @Departments. (conn = pymssql ... is already done!)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should give you some hint of how to script your requirement:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn=pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=<servername>;Trusted_Connection;user=<username>;password=<password>',autocommit = True)
cursor=cnxn.cursor()
department=raw_input('Enter department:')
query='EXEC [master].[dbo].[aaatest] '+department+''
cursor.execute(query)
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: After cursor executing, how to print out?

Comment: You can print by using fetchone. There are tutorials for this topic. Please search :)